# Calculate an operation with a negative number first in a string

Tags: java, android

I've just about written every possible combination of code I can think of, but I can't get my calculator to work if there is a negative operator first.

The way the calculator works is if there already contains an operator (with the last character of the string being a digit) it will calculate what's already there first and then add the operator pressed. However, I want it to allow and second operator if and only if the first character is a negative (- symbol). But I can't for the life of me do this. This is what I have so far:

```
// calculation logic
    public void calculate() {
            for (int i = 0; i < textField.length(); i++) {
                    checkOp(i);
            }
            resultDisplayed = true;
    }

    public float checkOp(int i) {
            if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '+') {
                    result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) + Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
                    returnAnswer(decimalFormat.format(result));
            } else if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '-') {
                    if (textField.getText().charAt(0) != '-') {
                            result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) - Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
                    } else {

                    }
            } else if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '*') {
                    result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) * Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
                    returnAnswer(decimalFormat.format(result));
            } else if (textField.getText().charAt(i) == '/') {
                    result = Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(0, i)) / Float.parseFloat(textField.getText().toString().substring(i + 1, textField.length()));
                    returnAnswer(decimalFormat.format(result));
            }

            return result;
    }

// checks if last character is one of the operands (not -)
    public void checkLastOp(String op) {
            if (textField.length() == 0 & op.equals("-")) {
                    addToOutput("-");
            } else if (textField.length() > 0) {
                    if (op.equals("+")) {
                            if (textField.getText().toString().contains("+") || textField.getText().toString().contains("-") || textField.getText().toString().contains("*") || textField.getText().toString().contains("/")) {
                                    if (Character.isDigit(textField.getText().charAt(textField.length() - 1)) && textField.getText().charAt(0) != '-') {
                                            calculate();
                                    } else {
                                            if (!Character.isDigit(textField.getText().charAt(textField.length() - 1))) {
                                                    textField.getText().delete(textField.getText().length() - 1, textField.getText().length());
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                            addToOutput("+");
                    } else if (op.equals("-")) {
                            if (textField.getText().toString().contains("+") || textField.getText().toString().contains("-") || textField.getText().toString().contains("*") || textField.getText().toString().contains("/")) {
                                    if (Character.isDigit(textField.getText().charAt(textField.length() - 1))) {
                                            calculate();
                                    } else if (textField.getText().charAt(textField.length() - 1) == '+' || textField.getText().charAt(textField.length() - 1) == '-') {
                                            textField.getText().delete(textField.getText().length() - 1, textField.getText().length());
                                    }
                            }
                            addToOutput("-");
                    } else if (op.equals("*")) {
                            if (textField.getText().toString().contains("+") || textField.getText().toString().contains("-") || textField.getText().toString().contains("*") || textField.getText().toString().contains("/")) {
                                    if (Character.isDigit(textField.getText().charAt(textField.length() - 1))) {
                                            calculate();
                                    } else {
                                            textField.getText().delete(textField.getText().length() - 1, textField.getText().length());
                                    }
                            }
                            addToOutput("*");
                    } else if (op.equals("/")) {
                            if (textField.getText().toString().contains("+") || textField.getText().toString().contains("-") || textField.getText().toString().contains("*") || textField.getText().toString().contains("/")) {
                                    if (Character.isDigit(textField.getText().charAt(textField.length() - 1))) {
                                            calculate();
                                    } else {
                                            textField.getText().delete(textField.getText().length() - 1, textField.getText().length());
                                    }
                            }
                            addToOutput("/");
                    }
            }
    }
```

CheckLastOp gets called when you press either +, -, *, or / and passes the appropriate operator through the method.

With my calculate method, I've tried checking if - is the first character, if it isn't proceed as normal, if it is calculate from the second value and minus the answer from zero.

**Edit:** Think I've spotted why it crashes. In my calculate method, if the first character is i, i stops at 0, it then calculates from 1 to i which is from 1 to 0, which is a complete mess. Now I need a way to go from 1 to the next character which would meaning calling calculate again, but not sure of a way to do this.

Rewrote calculation logic to tidy it up.

**Edit 2:** Solved it, updated my code to show my solution.

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()` instead.

Comment: So you want to do something like `-*3/3`, I'm wrong I hope?

Comment: you can use this 

if(text.contains("+"))

Comment: Fixed comparing strings with ==. Haven't done that in a while. And no not like that, I want to do -3+2 or anything with a negative first and a digit second. But this doesn't calculate.

Comment: If calculator is not the main objective of your project then there are tons of open source java math expression parsing libraries.You can use them

Comment: It is exactly the point of the project, hence it is a calculator. I don't want to use another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the trivial errors highlighted by the other commenter I think I'm missing something here. What you're trying to build is an expression parser, which is something usually built with a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Parser).

If you try to write it yourself, using nested ifs you'll probably end up missing some corner case, or spending a lot of time in unit testing.

The good news here is that Java supports by default the expression evaluation using the built-in Javascript-engine that you can find in JDK 1.6+.

Here's a snippet that you can easily adapt to your situation:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;

public class ExpressionEvaluator {

  private ExpressionEvaluator instance;
  private ScriptEngineManager scrEngMng;
  private ScriptEngine engine;

  private ExpressionEvaluator()
  {
    scrEngMng = new ScriptEngineManager();
    engine = scrEngMng.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
  }

  public static ExpressionEvaluator getInstance()
  {
    if(instance == null)
    {
       instance = new ExpressionEvaluator();
    }
    return instance;
  }

  public String eval(String expr) throws Exception{    
     return engine.eval(expr).toString();
   } 
}
```

Try it with your expression:

```
System.out.println(ExpressionEvaluator.getInstance().eval("your expression here"));
```

Please have a look to the [ScriptEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) class to understand how to handle return values and how to modify my eval function as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I managed to fix it earlier and never got round to updating the question which I'll do now. I'll keep this in mind next time I need something similar, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you need a recursive solution. In your problem statement you say that when the user presses the second operator, you first evaluate the existing expression and then add on the second operator. There should be no need for the recursive call to checkOp(j). Note: the first '-' is not an operator, but a symbol to denote a negative number and treat it as such.

That is unless you are trying to allow for brackets '[','(','{', in which case your expression evaluation is infinitely more complicated.